# Scrolling TableView in PageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have parent and child View controllers, in child view controller I have image view and table view. If table view's content size is less than screen size, it goes properly. But if content size is more than screen size, I can't scroll it.
In XCode Attributes Inspector I have these properties. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuxZ1.png
My code to generate Table View content:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
_mainArray = [self getAnswers];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSUInteger)section {
int height =  (_imageView.image == 0) ? 0 : 118;
return height;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getAnswers {
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pdd.sqlite"];
const char * dbpath = [defaultDBPath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_pdd_ab) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT RecNo, Picture, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, Answer5, RightAnswer, Comment FROM paper_ab WHERE PaperNumber = \"%@\" AND QuestionInPaper = \"%d\"", _randomNumbers[_index] , (int)_index + 1];
    const char * query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_pdd_ab, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSData *picture = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1)];
            _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:picture];
            for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
                if (sqlite3_column_text(statement, i) != NULL) {
                    NSString *arrayelement = [[NSString alloc]
                                              initWithUTF8String:
                                              (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];
                    [array addObject:arrayelement];
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Rezultatov net!");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Ne mogu vypolnit' zapros!");
    }
    sqlite3_close(_pdd_ab);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Ne mogu ustanovit' soedinenie!");
}
return array;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfSectionInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSUInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSUInteger)section {
return _mainArray.count - 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSUInteger rowNumber = [indexPath row];
static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (rowNumber == 0) {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _mainArray[0]];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
} else {
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld. %@", (long)rowNumber, _mainArray[rowNumber]];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
}
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = backView;
NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      cell.textLabel.font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                      nil];
CGRect textLabelSize = [cell.textLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:kExamenLabelFrameMaxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];
cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, textLabelSize.size.width, textLabelSize.size.height);
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSUInteger rowNumber = [indexPath row];
if ([self.rightAnswersArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:_index + 1]] ) { // делаю красиво, если пользователь возвращается к вопросу, на который уже правильно ответил
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    if (rowNumber == [_mainArray[_mainArray.count - 2] intValue]) { // если ответ правильный
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 / 255.0f green:152 / 255.0f blue:70 / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }
} else if ([self.wrongAnswersArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:_index + 1]] ) { // делаю красиво, если пользователь возвращается к вопросу, на который уже НЕправильно ответил
    long questnum = [self.wrongAnswersArray indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:_index + 1]];
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    if (rowNumber != [_mainArray[_mainArray.count - 2] intValue] && [NSNumber numberWithLong:rowNumber] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self.wrongAnswersSelectedArray objectAtIndex:questnum] intValue]]) {  // если ответ НЕправильный
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236 / 255.0f green:30 / 255.0f blue:36 / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }
}
}  
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSUInteger rowNumber = [indexPath row];
if (rowNumber == 0) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
} else {
    if (rowNumber == [_mainArray[_mainArray.count - 2] intValue]) { // если ответ правильный
        if ([settings boolForKey:@"needVibro"]) {
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); // вибрация при правильном ответе
        }
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 / 255.0f green:152 / 255.0f blue:70 / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
        [self.rightAnswersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:_index + 1]];
    } else { // если ответ неправильный
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236 / 255.0f green:30 / 255.0f blue:36 / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
        [self.wrongAnswersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:_index + 1]];
        [self.wrongAnswersSelectedArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowNumber]];
    }
}
NSUInteger wrongCount = _wrongAnswersArray.count;
NSUInteger rightCount = _rightAnswersArray.count;
NSLog(@"Номер вопроса - %d, правильных ответов - %d, неправильных ответов - %d", (int)_index + 1, (int)rightCount, (int)wrongCount);
if (rightCount + wrongCount == 20) {
    [self writeStatisticsToBase];
    [self getResultOfTest];
    [_timer invalidate];
}
}

- (void)getResultOfTest {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ResultExamen" sender:self];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSUInteger rowNumber = [indexPath row];
NSString *textLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld. %@", (long)rowNumber, _mainArray[rowNumber]];
NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
                                      nil];
CGRect textLabelSize = [textLabel boundingRectWithSize:kExamenLabelFrameMaxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];
return kExamenDifference + textLabelSize.size.height;
}
```

If I change properties "Bounces" and "Bounce Vertically" of Scroll View to enabled, I can scroll table view, but it return to its original state. You can see this situation on YouTube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rDd4oQQDB0

So, my question is how to scroll UITableView in UIPageViewController if table content size is more than screen size?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set bottom space to super view auto layout to your table-view manage scrolling according to device screen size.Bottom space to super-view auto-layout adjust your table-view bottom according to device screen size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please help me in another question : if I use "suggested constraints", at 3.5 inch my image view reduce, but I don't want it, I need only to set constraint to bottom of my table view. What I have to do? There are not so many materials of autolayout on my language...

Comment: you can add header of uitableview in xib of viewcontroller and then you can set the height constraints of imageview it will always appear in that size if you want to change the height of imageview than you can create a reference of nslayourconstraint to handle pragmatically in your code.